# Is splitting a video for export a good technique?

Tags: ffmpeg, after-effects, premiere, export, render

Currently, I'm making a video that I intend to upload to YouTube. I used After Effects and Premiere Pro for this. Since it's a video that's almost 2 hours long, the export takes me about 16 hours according to my PC specifications:

11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz, 2419 Mhz (I'm using the integrated GPU) Installed physical memory 8.00 GB.

The first question is, is it normal to have such high export times? From all the video tutorials I've seen, I haven't seen export times as high as mine, but I suppose it's due to the added effects and the length of the video.

Exporting for 16 hours straight is very inconvenient for me because I plan on continuing to upload videos, and if I have to leave each video for 16 hours or more, that means the laptop battery will deteriorate, and I also use the computer for university work. The solution I've come up with is to slice the video into several parts, export them, and then join them with ffmpeg, which I understand does not perform rendering (or something like that).

When I did it, it came out correctly, and there were no issues. The second question is that I would like to know if this technique has a name and how to do it correctly. I would also like to know if there are any disadvantages to doing it this way. I exported in H.264 at 1080p and 24 fps, and then I joined them, but there may be a better way to do it.

I'm asking this question because before attempting it, I searched the internet and didn't find much information about this technique. The information I found mentioned that there would be problems between frames because a frame contains information about its next frame, but I found that it worked for me, and in case of problems, the cut can be made just at scene changes so that it doesn't affect much.

Comment: On my 5 y.o comp, I've had a 3 min video that took ~25 mins to encode to h264 in an old AE. I made following calculation: 25/3 (min.et/min.vt) * 120 (min.vt) = 1000 (min.et), which is 1000/60 = 16.6 (h.et). Here `min.et`, `min.vt` and `h.et` represent minutes-encoding-time, minutes-video-time and hours-encoding-time, respectively. 16h to encode a 2h video doesn't seem overly long to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a few names used, but generally speaking you're talking "parallel encoding", Netflix and others dealing with large volumes of video data do this, you can dig into a lot more detail in their blog https://netflixtechblog.com/high-quality-video-encoding-at-scale-d159db052746

Given your described render times, it's certainly a good solution to prevent having to re-encode pieces over and over if you only change only part of your sequence, you just have to trade off against the manual disassembly/re-assembly times to do it this way, Netflix have built their own custom software for these tasks, I'm not aware of anything off the shelf for end users to automate this.